# What does Dafny know about loops with a break?

Tags: iteration, break, dafny

```
I am used to loops
```

```
while Grd
invariant Inv
{ ..}
assert Inv && !Grd;
```

with out any break  Dafny knows that `Inv && ! Grd`  is true  but:
Dafny does not check the loop invariant  after a `break;` command.  Hence

```
method tester(s:seq<int>) returns (r:int) 
ensures r <= 0
{   var i:nat := |s|;
    r := 0;
    while (i > 0)
       decreases i
       invariant r == 0;
    {   i := i -1;
        if s[i]< 0  { r:= s[i]; break;}        
    }    
   // assert r == 0; // invariant dose not hold
}

method Main() {
    var x:int := tester([1,-9,0]);
    print x,"\n";
}
```

Clearly Dafny understands that the invariant no longer holds. Could anyone tell me what dafny actually knows.

Answer (score 5):

If there are `break` statements, the condition after the loop is
the disjunction of `Inv && !Grd` and the conditions that hold at
the respective `break` statements.

Here's a more formal answer:

In the absence of any abrupt exits (like `break`) from a loop, the familiar
way to prove the Hoare triple

```
{{ P }}
while Grd
  invariant Inv
{
  Body
}
{{ Q }}
```

is to prove the following three conditions (I'm ignore termination):

0. Check that the loop invariant holds on entry to the loop:

```
P ==> Inv
```

1. Check that the loop invariant is maintained by the loop body:

```
{{ Inv && Grd }}
Body
{{ Inv }}
```

2. Check that the invariant and negated guard prove Q:

```
Inv && !Grd ==> Q
```

Let me rephrase conditions 1 and 2. To do that, I will start by
rewriting the while loop into a repeat-forever loop with breaks:

```
loop
  invariant Inv
{
  if !Grd {
    break;
  }
  Body
}
```

(In other words, I'm using `loop` as `while true`.) Proof obligation 1 above
can now be rephrased as proving

```
{{ Inv }}
if !Grd {
  break;
}
Body
{{ Inv }}
```

where you *don't* have to prove anything further along any path that reaches
a `break`.
Proof obligation 2 can be rephrased in a sort of dual way:

```
{{ Inv }}
if !Grd {
  break;
}
Body
{{ break: Q }}
```

by which I mean you don't have to prove anything if you reach the end of `...Body`,
but you do have to prove `Q` at any `break`.

What I just said also applies when `Body` contains other `break` statements. That's how Dafny treats loops (that is, condition 0 plus the rephrased conditions 1 and 2, plus termination checking).

Comment: I should leave questions unanswered more often. This is a great answer! :)